# Some cultures are missing when requesting CultureTypes.AllCultures

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I am trying to get the ISO name and currency for Ghana(en-GB) and some other countries but nothing is displaying. When I run the code, this is what I get.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Currency
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cul = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
        foreach (var curr in cul)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(curr.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + "  " 
                + curr.EnglishName + " " 
                + curr.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

SPOOLED RESULT

```
nn  Norwegian, Nynorsk (Norway) kr
pt  Portuguese (Portugal) ?
sr  Serbian (Latin, Serbia and Montenegro (Former)) Din.
sv  Swedish (Finland) ?
az  Azeri (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan) ???.
dsb  Lower Sorbian (Germany) ?
se  Sami, Northern (Sweden) kr
ga  Irish (Ireland) ?
ms  Malay (Brunei Darussalam) $
uz  Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan) ???
bn  Bengali (Bangladesh) ?
mn  Mongolian (Traditional Mongolian, PRC) 
iu  Inuktitut (Latin, Canada) $
tzm  Tamazight (Latin, Algeria) DZD
quz  Quechua (Ecuador) $
ar  Arabic (Egypt) ?.?.?
zh  Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) HK$
de  German (Austria) ?
en  English (Australia) $
es  Spanish (Spain, International Sort) ?
fr  French (Canada) $
sr  Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia and Montenegro (Former)) ???.
se  Sami, Northern (Finland) ?
quz  Quechua (Peru) S/.
```

Comment: How many cultures do you have in your `cul`? Which version of .NET Framework you using? I'm using .NET 4.5 and it gets 354 culture..

Comment: `en-gb` is English (United Kingdom), not Ghana.

Comment: Ghana doesn't have a dedicated language culture name.  Since 90% of the population speaks English and it was formerly part of the British Gold Coast, en-GB is a likely fallback.  So it would be covered by "en" in that list.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake Chris.

Comment: Seems to be that culture is "Akan" from the list: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gFjRHi

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
Console.WriteLine(culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
Console.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
```

You should remember that your console window can't display all the cultures at the same time.Try writing them to a text file then check it's content:

```
var cul = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

var lines = cul
           .Select(x => string
                .Join(" ", x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, x.EnglishName, x.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol));

File.WriteAllLines("cultures.txt",lines);
```